# How to name SQL Column with same meaning as Table name?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table named `instruction`. This table has a column which is also named `instruction` and is of type `varchar(8192)` containing required instructions as text:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `instruction` (
    `instruction_id` BIGINT,
    `instruction`    VARCHAR(8192),

    PRIMARY KEY (`instruction_id`)
);
```

As one can see, the name `instruction` not only seems to be a bit redundant but also weird - at least to me. I've tried to find some answers to this specific case but couldn't find any. So here's my question about this particular use case:

- Is there a convention or best practice of how to name the column when the only column has the same meaning as the table?
- What about using `data` for the column name, although this name might mislead a bit?
- What do enterprise applications name their column when normalizing this way?

Comment: `text` or `description` maybe?

Comment: I prefer plural table names, since a table (usually) has more than one row. I.e. I'd choose instructions as table name, and instruction as column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem, but there is no general "best" solution to it.

One option is to use plural names for tables. Thus `instructions.instruction` would be one instruction of all instructions. The plural form feels especially good in the `FROM` clause, because you select from all the instructions, but in the other clauses of a query the singular form looks better, because you don't want all `users.name = 'John'`, but one `user.name = 'John'` for instance. While they tried to get SQL close to human language, it isn't that close that you can use plural and singular interchangeably :-) Still, using plurals for table names is a viable option.

Apart from this, you can use general names like `text`, `description`, `content`, etc. I've seen databases where hundeds of lookup tables consisted of exactly two columns: code and text, and only the table name (country, curreny, ...) told you what the code and text refered to. This is also a good option.

Then you can just call the column exactly as the table, and there is nothing wrong with this. Even more: You won't see queries with `instruction.instruction` (which admittedly does look a bit weird), because: when do you ever qualify a column with the completely spelled name? You would rather see just `instruction` or `i.instruction`, depending on whether your query refers to one or more tables.

There is no "best" way to deal with this in my opinion. Just decide for one and stay consistent.

Comment: *I've seen databases where hundeds of lookup tables consisted of exactly two columns.* So when big databases in enterprise applications go with ordinary column names like `content` I'm beginning to think that this could be a thing for me too. To name the table plural is imo not this consistent since all other tables are singular - and I'm not convinced enough to break this personal rule. Many thanks for your insights.

Comment: quote 1. "instruction.instruction (which admittedly does look a bit weird), because: when do you ever qualify a column with the completely spelled name? You would rather see just instruction or i.instruction"  ****  quote 2. "but in the other clauses of a query the singular form looks better, because you don't want all users.name = 'John', but one user.name = 'John'" end quotes. Is it possible to use u.name = John like it is common to use i.instruction ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I'd expect the table name to be a level of abstraction higher than the columns.

For example, an `person` table with `first_name` and `last_name` would make sense (as opposed to a `name` table).

Depending on what kind of instruction you are dealing with, there might be a more general name, though it's far easier to think what that is when you have two columns.

If you had many instructions, what would that constitute? Maybe a manual, program, cycle, or guidebook?

There is the possibility that there just isn't a better name for the table, but it's worth nailing it now rather than going through your non-breaking database refactoring process later.

Comment: Yeah, if it were that easy to abstract further I would have the solution ;). The problem is, that I don't know what instruction especially will be put into the db. And there are sometimes more than one. So the table has to be named `instruction` or  `instructions`, cause that's what the table is for. If I'd differentiate further, e.g. 1:m with different kind of instructions, I'd need some kind of order too. Having one text holding all instructions, markdown formatted or maybe JSON styled is at least for my use case I think a viable way to go. Many thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, there was an old school rule saying that table names should be in plural and column names in singular. Obeying that forgotten practice you will have the answer to your question - table INSTRUCTIONS has a column INSTRUCTION.

It is simple, ease to remember and if consistent it can be quite usefull. Look at  it like if you need a particular instruction out of a full box of them, how would you say it:

```sql
Select INSTRUCTION From INSTRUCTIONS Where ID = 3;
```